# How do I test for an invalid WordPress WP_Query query?

Tags: wordpress

I have a page template which displays a list of post summaries, depending on a user-defined custom query, which is supplied using the `post_content`, for example:

```
category_name=blog
```

This is then passed to `WP_Query()` which will return however many 'blog' posts there are.

However, if I pass a completely invalid query (or simply make a mistake) such as:

```
the rain in spain falls mainly on the plain
```

`WP_Query->get_posts()` will return ALL posts in the database, rather than letting me know that the query is meaningless / erroneous.

Is there a built-in method to test for invalid queries?

Currently, I'm doing a `parse_str()` to convert the query to an array, then an `array_intersect_keys()` against a list of valid query parameters I've compiled from the `WP_Query` page.

It works, but feels pretty hacky - am I missing something?

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a failed query catch built in to WP like you are asking for (I wish there were, too).

However, there may be a cleaner hack. `wp_count_posts` will return a count of all posts in the database. And `wp_query` will return a count of its results in `$post_count`. One thing you could do is a check on your query - if the result of `wp_count_posts` is equal to `$post_count` then you know something is wrong.

It's not as clean as a 'no results' response, but perhaps more straight forward than your current solution.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query (search the page for $post_count)

Comment: Thanks Matt, I thought of that too, but surely that would provide a false positive for queries that returned all posts from the database, such as `posts_per_page=-1` ?